# Which flavour Ubuntu for Ubuntu Console Only?

Tags: vim, console

I'm a Web Developer.

I've got an old Netbook computer.

I want to learn VIM and force myself to use the terminal to create a small NodeJS or Python project and fumble around in the dark with a text-only browser :)

Do you have any advice on which Ubuntu flavour I should use if I only want to run Ubuntu in Console mode? Is there a version that comes without a GUI but does have video, networking and wifi drivers, etc so I can be productive?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Ubuntu Server has a command line interface but no GUI. Therefore, it will not install any video drivers. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hello @Jos - My Netbook has a display (like a laptop does). If I use Ubuntu Server (without any video drivers), can I still see something on the screen or is Ubuntu Server designed to be run without a monitor? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Turtle10000 - So far I've learnt that I can install any modern Linux distro and change the boot settings so the Desktop isn't loaded but my initial thought around that is the distro comes bloated with apps that I'll never need so I was hoping there was knowledge out there to find something like an Ubuntu Console Edition. I agree it's similar to the post you relate to but I'm not asking how to disable the Desktop so it is a different question. Thanks

Comment: Yes, what you call Console Edition is in fact Ubuntu Server. It can use a monitor - in fact you need one to install the system - but as soon as it is running happily, you can disconnect the monitor, and connect to it through `ssh` when necessary.